# Mixing generics, non-generics and base class design question

Tags: c#

My app deals with different formats of data. Let's say two for this example: TypeA and TypeB. So I created an IFormatter interface:

```
interface IFormatter
{
   bool SomeOtherProp { get; }
   string Serialize(object o);
   T Deserialize<T>(string s);
}
```

Then I created two classes for the implementation:

```
class TypeAFormatter : IFormatter
{
}

class TypeBFormatter : IFormatter
{
}
```

I also have a 3rd container type class. This holds the content type and the serialized / formatted data:

```
public Content
{
  public string ContentType { get; private set; }
  public byte[] Data { get; private set; }
}
```

In one area of my app, I deal with creating the Content object:

```
void SomeMethodForTypeA()
{
   _content = new Content(new TypeAFormatter(), theContent);
}

void SomeMethodForTypeB()
{
   _content = new Content(new TypeBFormatter(), theContent);
}
```

The constructor for Content does the following:

```
Content(IFormatter formatter, object content)
{
  Data = formatter.Serialize(content);
}
```

In another area of my app, I have a List of IFormatters:

```
List<IFormatter> lstFormatters;
```

And when data comes in, I loop through the list and pick the right formatter for the type of incoming data and call the Deserialize method:

```
formatter.Deserialize<T>(data);
```

So this is all working fine.

The problem is, the IFormatter interface Deserialize is a generic, which is what I need, but the TypeAFormatter can deal with any type T, while the TypeBFormatter is specifically for dealing with string only.

So I ended up doing this:

```
    public override string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(string))
            throw new Exception("must be string");

    public override T Deserialize<T>(string obj)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != typeof(string))
            throw new Exception("must be string);
```

This also "works". But I'm not liking the manual type checks. I originally started off as making IFormatter an IFormatterT instead and making them look like:

```
public class TypeAFormatter<T> : IFormatter<T>
public class TypeBFormatter : IFormatter<string>
```

Which solved the problem on the creation side, but I can't have a list of IFormatterT's and call the typed methods without a bunch of reflection and then it ends up pretty much getting boxed as an object anyways.

Any approach I can take where I don't have to do the type checking, but can still call them generically for the deserialize?

Answer (score 1):

Have both a generic and non-generic version of the interface and use them depending on whether you know the compile-time type or not.

```
interface IFormatter
{
   string Serialize(object o);
   object Deserialize(string s);
}

interface IFormatter<T> : IFormatter
{
   string Serialize(T o);
   T Deserialize<T>(string s);
}
```

The implementation of `IFormatter<T>` would then just forward the non-generic `Serialize` and `Deserialize` implementations to their generic counterparts. Also, the non-generic methods would embed the appropriate type checks—usually implemented in a class that implements the generic version and hence has access to the type parameter `T`. Like this:

```
public string Serialize(object o)
{
    if (!(o is T)) throw ...;
    return Serialize<T>(o);
}

public string Serialize<T>(T o)
{
    // actual serialization code
}
```

Further, you might want to have a method in the non-generic version to check whether the implementation can handle a specific type:

```
CanFormat(Type type);  // in case you know the type only
CanFormat(object obj); // in case you know the value
```

Then you could pick the correct formatter like this:

```
var formatter = allFormatters.FirstOrDefault(f => f.CanFormat(myType));
```

Comment: Yeah, you're still doing the type check which is what I'm doing now. I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: You can't avoid it at all. Encapsulate it.

Comment: I just found a way to do it without type checks actually. IFormatter just has T Deserialize<T>(); and IFormatterT has string Serialize(T t);. Then I have a Content which holds just the common properties and ContentT which takes a typed parameter for the serialize. So TypeAFormatter becomes IFormatter<T>, IFormatter and TypeBFormatter becomes IFormatter<string>, IFormatter.

Comment: The Serialize and Deserialize get split into 2 different interfaces a generic and non-generic and so does Content. So on the creation side I can use the typed / generic methods and on the read side I can use the generic method.

Comment: Not sure I like splitting up the interface lol, but it seems a little cleaner then putting type checks everywhere.